# Set Width of gridview columns dynamically when AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, vb.net

I have a problem in setting the width of the gridview when i used the property AutoGenerateColumns to AutoGenerateColumns="true". And the gridview is databind in code behind. If i am using gridview1.columns(0).width it raise error.

And the GridView1.Columns.Count is always zero because the grid view is databind.

In .aspx: -

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

In code behind

```
Dim strCon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=myDataBaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=GKRANJAN;Password=abcdef")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from myTableName", strCon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Hence myTableName has more columns and i dont like to add them through BoundFiled because they vary in my case.

In GridView1_RowDataBound i used : -

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
Dim cell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(0)
            cell.Width = New Unit("200px")
    End Sub
```

But it could not work for me. Please help me!!

Thanks to all!!

Comment: Provide a full `RowDataBound` method body. What do you check in it with `If` clause?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy sorry it was added by mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got it.

Below is the .aspx page: -

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 

        style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="1000px">        

        <!-- Mind the above two lines to make this trick effective you must have to use both properties as is; -->

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is the Code behind: -

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strCon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=myDataBaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=GKRANJAN;Password=abcdef")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from myTableName", strCon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

            'For first column set to 200 px
            Dim cell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(0)
            cell.Width = New Unit("200px")

            'For others set to 50 px
            'You can set all the width individually

            For i = 1 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
                'Mind that i used i=1 not 0 because the width of cells(0) has already been set
                Dim cell2 As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(i)
                cell2.Width = New Unit("10px")
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Actually when we use boundfields then gridview columns width renders in browser as we set the widths of each and every columns. I used two methods in two projects - that is one by taking bound fields with AutoGenerateColumns="false" and another by setting the AutoGenerateColumns = "true" - individually in two project and then when page got rendered in browser, i used "View Source" functionality of browser and then realized that what is the main difference in both types. The difference is as: -

```
style="table-layout:fixed;"
```

I also added the below lines in my .aspx page at gridview tag: -

```
style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="1000px"
```

And now it's working fine.

Thanks to All!!

Comment: For me it worked well without the : Width="1000px" But maybe this is, because I use something like cell2.Width = New Unit("10%") and calculate the width fo each cell in percent.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if its just a typo(or you omitted it) but your code on the RowDataBound part is missing the IF part..

But youre on the right track. Me, i use some thing like this and it works all the time

```
Protected Sub gvData_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvData.RowDataBound
     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Width = New Unit("200px")
            e.Row.Cells(1).Width = New Unit("500px")
     End If
 End Sub
```

But remember, the gridview is rendered a table. So cells will resize itself to the longest content.

Comment: The same happened with me. The table is resized and all the work done becomes worthless. @noisyass2

Answer (score 2):

If you are not intending to make the grid in fixed mode (ie. expecting a overflow behaviour as there are large number of columns) then the above solution with style="table-layout:fixed;" is not the appropriate one.

e.g. see the below scenario:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

In this such case just set the cell Width to specific value and Set Cell Wrap to False

```
Protected Sub gvData_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvData.RowDataBound
     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Width = New Unit("200px") 
        e.Row.Cells(0).Wrap = false
     End If
End Sub
```