# how can i change column width in base to content with vb.net and bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I have a GridView in vb.net and show it in a window Modal with bootstrap, but I can't make that the columns with more information be readable.
how can i change column width in base to content?
I don't know if is for the use of gridView.

I thought that maybe the problem was the modal or my CSS classes but I made an example with out my clases and even with any bootstrap class on the div and the result is the same. I suppose that can be the way to vb.net convert the gridvie to html tags.
This is an example of my asp code:

```
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <HeaderStyle/>
                <emptydatatemplate>
                    <asp:image id="NoDataImage" imageurl="~/images/notData.png" alternatetext="No Image" runat="server"/>
                    <label class="alert-danger">Data Not found :S</label>
                </emptydatatemplate>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center"/>                              
            </asp:GridView>             
        </div>
        <!-- end tester table -->
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image: table with only one row]

For example the twelve column is difficult to read.
 Any idea is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534388/4574359

Comment: Trap them in RowDataBound property of the gridview. You can customize them in any manner you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing datagridview property **AutoResizeColumsMode** to **Fill**

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

For more information use [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

you can also use **DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode Property**

```
DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```